# Quark Transitions and Convservation of Energy

Tags: particle-physics, quarks

My question is essentially: How is conservation of energy held in quark transitions?

Several quark transitions seem to break energy conservation, such as

$$ d \rightarrow c W^{-}$$
$$d \rightarrow t W^{-}$$

where the masses are
$$m_{d} \approx 3-7 \ \textrm{MeV}$$
$$m_{c} \approx 1.25\ \textrm{GeV}$$
$$m_{t} \approx 172\ \textrm{GeV}$$
$$m_{W^{-}} \approx 80.4 \ \textrm{GeV}$$
Are all these transitions (and others) forbidden according to conservation of energy? Clearly they are perfectly allowed transitions, and so my intuition tells me the reason is due to the effective masses of quarks within a bound system.

Comment: Those $W^{-}$ are off-mass shell particles (virtual particles). In the case of off-mass shell particles $E^2-p^2\neq m^2$ - so they can have any mass as long as the energy-momentum between initial and final state is conserved. You can consider $80.4$ GeV as a mean of the invariant mass distribution of the W boson - the mass that W is most likely to have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> intuition tells me the reason is due to the effective masses of quarks within a bound system.

Your intuition confuses you because you are trying to use a type of "conservation of mass", (identifying mass with energy), a classical concept, instead of conservation of energy and momentum which makes life simple. One has to work with [four vectors.](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/vec4.html)

If the coupling constants exist, and the center of mass energy of the "system" under consideration allows the generation of the rest masses of the particles, the reaction can become physical.

A simpler example than quarks comes from the inverse beta decay. The free neutron decays into a proton because it is energetically allowed, as the proton has a smaller mass than the neutron. BUT in a nucleus the inverse process is a allowed, taking energy from the nuclear system, the proton turning into a neutron,  [$β^{+}$ decay.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/411911/quark-transitions-and-convservation-of-energy) .

Having said the above, I am curious in where did you find a d to top transition, which would have to go with higher order diagrams, still following four momentum algebra. [This is the table](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/qrkdec.html) of the straight forward couplings in quark decays,

Comment: Is it correct to say that energy required comes from the binding energy?
My question arose from a homework assignment regarding Feynman diagrams for a particle physics class

Comment: in the nuclear example yes, the final nucleus is energetically more tightly bound. In the case of scatterings the energy comes from the beam. It can be off mass shell. The quarks are always virtual after  all and have to be within a hadronic system.